# Xcode: On debug, is there any way to prevent it from opening the navigator on the front-most window?

Tags: xcode, debugging, navigator

I'm trying to figure out how to use Xcode in a multi-window setup. I would like to have one window be my main window, and then have others that I use to do occasional spot editing. Here's the rub: I never want to have the navigator (or the debug console, for that matter) open in those other windows. I only want the navigator and console to open in the main window.

Right now, when I run the app the debug navigator and console open up in whichever window is frontmost (causing me to have both the main window and the secondary window with console pains and navigator open). Is there anyway to prevent the console and issue navigator from opening on the secondary window while preserving this behavior for the main window?

Comment: this behavior is so obnoxious, apple is not even caring

Answer (score 39):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want - but you can configure some of these things in the Xcode preferences under "Behaviors". Under "Running" you can click on "Starts" and it will show you the behaviors for when you run your application. You can set it to show a particular tab in the active window or a separate window. You can set up that tab to contain just the debugger. If it does show the debugger in the other tabs, you can minimize the debugger panes, and I believe it will save that state for the next time it launches. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-alerts_preferences/Recipe.html) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Go to Xcode -> Behaviors -> edit behaviors. Now under build and running uncheck shows Navigator.

Comment: it actually doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode `Preferences > Behaviours > Runnings > Generates output`, uncheck *Show debugger with Current Views*.

Comment: this doesn't work either

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you.